Is it possible to Airdrop a keystroke logger or other bugging software?
While shooting stills and video of an event, using my iPhone 15 Pro Max, a fellow asked if I would share my shots with him via AirDrop. I stopped and did that. Then I asked if he would send me what he had shot. I switched my AirDrop to Everyone and accepted his AirDrop transfer. Is that alone enough to facilitate transferring a keystroke logger or other bugging software?
It was noisy and I was distracted but I'm pretty sure my phone remained in the Photos app the entire time, including after he sent his photos (meaning, the Files app did not open on my iPhone, which would happen if he had AirDropped a file using the Files app).

You can transfer any kind of file via AirDrop, but if it's software, it won't be installed automatically. You would have to open it and click through an alert.
That said, there are risks in allowing an untrusted party to transfer data to your device. It could be something that would implicate you in a crime.

Very good point about receiving a file, @Linc Davis.  TU

Even if a bad actor did transfer some malware to your iPhone you'd have to explicitly tap to install it. Even if you did that, it's coming from outside the App Store, so it won't automatically run. You'd have to go into Settings, accept the signing certificate, reboot your phone, enter the passcode, say yes I trust the software... It's just incredibly unlikely to happen without you noticing.

Thank you, very illuminating @jsd!
